# Change button image on click

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is there a way I can change a button image on click?

At the moment I am using circles over an image which I am switching between red and green. is there a way I can automate these into buttons that will change colour on click?

Comment: any screenshot?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].